# Include doesn't work inside Rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, module

Consider I have a class located in `/lib/foo/bar/baz.rb`, defined as following:

```
module Foo
  module Bar
    class Baz
      def initialize
        self.name = 'Baz'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I also have the following controller `/controllers/my_controller.rb`, defined as following:

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  def index
    render json: ::Foo::Bar::Baz.new
  end
end
```

which outputs JSON `{name: "Baz"}` as one would expect.

The problem is if I try to include the `Foo::Bar` module, so I don't have to prepend it to the `Baz` class name each time I want to use it:

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  include ::Foo::Bar

  def index
    render json: ::Baz.new
  end
end
```

Returns me the following error message: `uninitialized constant Baz`.

Why???

Comment: Remove the `::` in `render json: ::Baz`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try

```
include ::Foo::Bar
...
render json: Baz.new
```

Comment: Classes can't be included.

Comment: Yes, I mistaken. It was 3am when I answered.

Answer (score 0):

`::Baz` ensures finding the module `Baz` in the top level namespace, so you should not use this syntax. `render json: Baz.new` should work.